# Highlighting all match words TypeScript

Tags: string, typescript, search, replace

Currently, I'm trying to implement highlighting on searched word in a text in my Angular project. I have the search operation as a separated component and I want to create a pipe that will highlight all the matches of the searched word in the text..

```
@Pipe({name: 'highlight'})
export class TextHighLightPipe implements PipeTransform {

 constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
 }

 transform(text: any, search: string): SafeHtml {

 //takes care of any special characters
 if (search !== undefined && search !== null) {
   search = search.toString().replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
 }
 text += '';
 return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(search ? text.replace(new RegExp(search, 'gi'),
   '<span style="background-color: yellow">' + `${search}` + '</span>') : text);
 }
}
```

This code works fine but it replaces all the matches with the searched word, so in case that I have a word that starts with upper case, when I search it with lower case, the transform function will replace it will the lower case one, which is the actual problem..
For example:

Text to search in: **This** is just an example text of **this** code

Search word: **this**

Result: **this** is just an example text of **this** code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. So I only had to change this piece of code:

```
return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(search ? text.replace(new RegExp(search, 'gi'),
  '<span style="background-color: yellow">' + `${search}` + '</span>') : text);
```

}

To this:

```
return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(search ? text.replace(new RegExp(`(${search})`, 'gi'),
  '<span style="background-color: yellow">' + `$1` + '</span>') : text);
```